# Where can I find a Free Chinese Handwritten Recognition engine for Android/IPhone?

Tags: android, neural-network, cjk, image-recognition

I am interested in developing something that will make use of Chinese handwritten recognition software on smart phones. Before I get started I wanted to check to see if there was any free (for open source and commercial applications) tools already developed for use. I've tried searching myself but I couldn't find any that stood out specifically for use on IPhone or Android.

Are there any free to use (for commercial purposes included) engines/frameworks for Chinese Handwritten Recognition? If so, where can I find them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=elAKT5DQKMP_ggfipIyBDw&ved=0CBoQBSgA&q=Free+Chinese+Handwriting+Recognition+engine+for+Android/IPhone&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a832e4bee034e5be&biw=1280&bih=685

IMO.
http://tegaki.org/

Comment: My impression of Tegaki, and I have looked at it, is that its GPL v.3. I may be wrong, but GPL 3 is copyleft and you can't really use it for a commercial project?

Comment: you arent going to find much for a "commercial project" unless you write them and get written permission, and I don't mean "Tegaki" I mean engines in general, most people that take the time to write such items aren't going to hand it out for you to make money off of, if you have a good idea with it and such your best bet is to mail them.

Answer (score 1):

My impression of Tegaki, and I have looked at it, is that its GPL v.3. I may be wrong, but GPL 3 is copyleft and you can't really use it for a commercial project? – user1137858 Jan 9 at 2:36

that is COMPLETELY wrong.  it's so wrong i don't even know where to start.  there isn't a single thing right about the 2nd sentence, other than it's grammatically correct and to your credit you do have the phrase "I may be wrong" in it.  please do take the time to find out about the GPLv3, and how many commercial projects there are which use that software license.  i will leave it to you to do this research for yourself.