# Chinese handwriting recognition library for android

Tags: android, ocr, cjk, handwriting

Does anyone know a free Chinese handwriting engine? I already check this question: [Where can I find a Free Chinese Handwritten Recognition engine for Android/IPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783290/where-can-i-find-a-free-chinese-handwritten-recognition-engine-for-android-iphon)

On the tegaki website I see that android is supported. However I can't find any *.jar files or anything I can import to my android project. (in eclipse with ADT)

Now I am searching for a small getting started guide for tegaki or an alternative. By the way I found this function in the google translate app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5hcHBzLnRyYW5zbGF0ZSJd

Something similar to that would be perfect. I wonder whether this part of the android sdk or open source. Unfortunatly I could't find it on the developer site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google translate feature is proprietary, and the actual recognition is done on Google's servers, so there is no library.

Where did you find info on Tegaki supporting Android? BTW, you can use the underlying recognition engine ([zinnia](http://zinnia.sourceforge.net)) on Android, and its license is permissive. You just have to compile with the NDK and write a JNI wrapper. It works for any language, you just have to train it for Chinese.

Comment: They mentioned it on their site in the development section: "Android or Iphone support" http://tegaki.org/
Thanks for the help. I will have a closer look at NDK and JNI wrapper.

Comment: It actually says 'Areas in which we welcome contributions include: Android or Iphone support', as in looking for people to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

There is HanziLookup, a good ole' Java Swing component that recognizes Chinese handwriting input: http://kiang.org/jordan/software/hanzilookup/

More recently there is HanziLookupJS, a Javascript port with an updated algorithm an alternative new dataset: https://github.com/gugray/HanziLookupJS

Both are open-source and pretty straightforward in case you need to port them to a different platform.